# Animate Infinite Scrolling Background Image

Tags: html, css, wordpress, jquery-animate, css-animations

I want to infinite Scroll Background image animate. How can I set it just go upwards continuously, not come back down? still, it gives a jerk.
How it is possible? Please help anyone know it.

I have a link:
http://herinshah.com/wp/fortiflex/5-2/

CSS:

```
.et_pb_section.landing-page .et_pb_column_3_5 {
  background-color: #f6eb00;
  margin-right: 1%;
  padding: 0 10px;
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url(images/ragazzi-logo.png);
  background-position: 0 0;
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-animation: upward 15s linear infinite;
  animation: upward 15s linear infinite;
  border-right: 4px solid #000;
  display: block;
  background-repeat: repeat-y;
}

@-webkit-keyframes upward {
  to {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
  from {
    background-position: 0 2174px;
  }
}

@keyframes upward {
  to {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
  from {
    background-position: 0 2174px;
  }
}
```

Comment: please add your code

Comment: Hi, Xenio can you please check I added CSS code.

Comment: @HAPPYSINGH add your html code which you have tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap a `div` inside a `div`. Here is the working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tq3p9m1a/1/) for the same
HTML

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="holder"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
     *{
      margin:0;
      padding:0
    }

    .main {
      height: 100vh;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    .holder {
      height: 200vh;
      -webkit-animation: upwards 2.5s linear infinite;
      animation: upward 2.5s linear infinite;
      background: url(http://herinshah.com/wp/fortiflex/wp-content/themes/Divi/images/ragazzi-logo.png)  center yellow;
      background-size: 100% 50%;
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes upward {
     from {
        background-position: 0% 0%;
    }
    to {
        background-position: 0% -100%;
     }
    }

    @keyframes upward {
      from {
        background-position: 0% 0%;
    }
    to {
        background-position: 0% -100%;
     }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, dear for giving me the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

I felt so compelled to answer this because I've done something similar :before (pun intended) and your skipping animation was giving me cancer.

You're gonna need to mess around with the pseudo :after element and get the height right. This should get you started.

Also your image isn't cropped perfectly right, so fix that and you'll be good to go.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Test</title>
  </head>
  <body onload="onloaded()">
    <div class="foo_section">
      <div class="foo_container">
        <img class="foo_image" src="http://herinshah.com/wp/fortiflex/wp-content/themes/Divi/images/ragazzi-logo.png" />
      </div> 
    </div>
  </body>
</html>

.foo_section {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  min-height: 400px;
}

.foo_container {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  animation: infiniteScrollBg 10s infinite linear;
}

.foo_container:after {
  content: "";
  height: 500%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #f6eb00;
  background-image: url('http://herinshah.com/wp/fortiflex/wp-content/themes/Divi/images/ragazzi-logo.png');
  background-size: 100% 20%;
}

.foo_image {
  width: 100%;
}

@-webkit-keyframes infiniteScrollBg {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(-100%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(-200%);
  }
}
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MMGLxE)

I see you're using Elegant Themes too. <3 Divi builder

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to have two `div` tags with the same `background`. Then, animate the same `div` and play with positioning of the `divs` and animate to make it look continuously scrolling up.

```
.container{
  width:600px;
  height:400px;
  background-color:yellow;
  margin:0 auto;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.bg{
  width:100%;
  height:400px;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size:contain;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
}
.bg.bg1{
  transform: translate(0,0);
   animation: upward 3s linear infinite;
}
.bg.bg2{
  transform: translate(0,100%);
  animation: upward2 3s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes upward {
    to {
         transform: translate(0,-100%);
    }
    from {
       transform: translate(0, 0);
    }
}
@keyframes upward2 {
    to {
      transform: translate(0,0);
    }
    from {
      transform: translate(0,100%);
    }
}
```

Here's how I would do it. [my codepen](https://codepen.io/butch182/pen/pXVGqP).

Comment: Thanks for suggesting dear Romel Indemne. I have no idea how to set?  you have any demo link.